# Split polygon with polygon in different tables / layers

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a large number (1 million+) multi point polygons (red lines, table_a), in which are around 20 million other multi point polygons (black blocks table_b). They are in separate tables. What i want to do is measure the sum of the area of the black blocks within the red line.

My workflow is to first cut the black blocks along the red line then use `st_intersection` to select them and sum using `st_area`.

Something like

`SET table_a
 UPDATE bldg_footprint = st_area (cut_buildings)
 FROM table_b 
 WHERE ST_Intersects( admin_bound table_a , buildings table_b )`

I can see from this answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169734/how-to-split-a-polygon-by-a-polygon-using-postgis). That I can either the blocks directly using the polygon or first extract the lines and then cut using lines.

My question is wether there's a function in PostGIS that is more efficient than that approach?

I'd be open to a QGIS solution but had assumed that given the size of data PostGIS will be faster.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant or efficient way of solving the problem but it worked for me;

The following cuts the black blocks using the red lines and returns the measurement of the cut blocks falling within the red line;

`SELECT boundaries.postcode,
    boundaries.pc_sectors,
    ST_Intersection(boundaries.pc_unit_geom, bldgs.geom) AS bldgs_split,--splits the black blocks
    ST_Area (st_intersection(boundaries.pc_unit_geom, bldgs.geom)) as bldg_area --returns area of the split blocks, as individual records
   FROM d_os_vectormap_bldgs bldgs,
    d_os_codepoint_poly boundaries
  WHERE st_intersects(boundaries.pc_unit_geom, bldgs.geom) --selects blocks within the boundary`

I then passed the results of that query to another, as below, to get the sum of all the block by boundary area, you could do this by modifying the original query using `group by`.

`SELECT
SUM (bldg_area) as sum_bldg_footprint,
boundary_id
from buildings_clipped_to_boundaries
GROUP BY boundary_id`

**NB** Make sure you have an index on the geometry columns or this will be very slow.