# Convert multipoint polygon boundary to line

Tags: qgis, postgis, polygon, splitting

In relation to this question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252227/split-polygon-with-polygon-in-different-tables-layers) as the image below.
I have a multipolygon geometry (red lines) that i want to turn into lines so i can use it to split another multipoint polygon (black blocks) using `ST_Split`. [image].

Is there a function equivalent to `ST_ExteriorRing` that works on multipolygons?
I've tried:

```
SELECT ST_Split(bldgs.geom, ST_Boundary(admin_boundary))
FROM admin_boundary, bldgs
WHERE admin_boundary.borders = 'N4 2';
```

> ERROR:  Splitting a Polygon by a MultiLineString is unsupported

`ST_ExteriorRing` can't be used because it won't work on multipolygons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to use [ST_Dump](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html)

From the manual:

> ST_Dump is useful for expanding geometries. It is the reverse of a
>   GROUP BY in that it creates new rows. For example it can be use to
>   expand MULTIPOLYGONS into POLYGONS.

In your case the query would likely look like:

```
WITH polygons AS (
  SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom 
  FROM admin_boundary
  WHERE admin_boundary.borders = 'N4 2'
)
SELECT 
 ST_Split(bldgs.geom, admin_boundary) geom
FROM bldgs a 
LEFT JOIN polygons b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
```

Comment: How does that work in the above context?

Comment: I've added an example. While checking the docs, I noticed though that cutting with multipolygons shouldn't be a problem. From the ST_Split documentation: When a (multi)polygon is passed as as the blade, its linear component (the boundary) is used for cutting the input.

Comment: Yes, i re-read that and was part of my problem in the above both are multipolygons so the black building blockslayer needs to be turned into lines before being passed to ST_Split

Comment: Then I would advise you to update your question, or even put a new one. Because the current question and answer don't make sense in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the create a custom function ST_SplitPolygon as written [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3097). This function allows a multipolygon to be cut by  a multline blade